# Problem with parsing String convertion to int in java

Tags: java

**Please help me for conversion my line of codes are mention below:**

```
String deptName = "IT";
String dept_test = request.getParameter("deptName").trim();
System.out.println("Dept name vlue is"+dept_test);
// problem here for casting...
int dept_id = Integer.parseInt(dept_test);
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? What is the content of dept_test when the problem occurs?

Comment: So what's the problem?  Whats your error message? Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any casting problems.  If your text doesn't contain a parseable number you will get a NumberFormatException which you may need to catch with a try/catch block.  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code the most you get will be an error parsing the input (including if it is none.  What may be an issue is that the variable `deptName` is never used. Did you mean to make the second line

```
String dept_test = request.getParameter(deptName).trim();
```

(notice no quotes) instead?

Comment: Dear Kathy Van, thanks a lot... My problem has resolved... can u send me your email address... its will may b helpfull for me.. I will wait for your rpl.. my id is awaiskhan80 on skype.. plz do the needfull.